# Scaffolding DB Context from existing database in layered architecture

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

I have an existing database which I am using in a CRM project developed in asp.net MVC project. Now our company has decided to develop HRM system also using the same database. The business requirement is to use Clean Architecture with .net core 3.1 as a backend for HRM. The project is structured in a way that it has four layers.

**Presentation Layer**: Contains Controllers and Web API endpoints.
**Application Layer**: Contains Application wise logic and types.
**Business Layer**: Contains Enterprise wise logic and types.
**Infrastructure Layer**: Contains all the cross-cutting concerns.

Presentation Layer and Infrastructure Layer are dependent on Application Layer and Application Layer is dependent on Business Layer. The business layer is independent of every other layer.

I have to scaffold the DB Context and Entities from the existing database so that Entities will go to the business layer and DB Context will go to the Infrastructure layer (Note: Infrastructure is not dependent on Business). How can I do that? Is there anyone who has done this earlier? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want the entity models in the business layer? IMHO I would prefer splitting up data context models from the business object models - that way the business layer is not dependent on the specific database structure.

Comment: Following clean architecture, so entities should go in the domain and context should in Infrastructure. we will access the entities through the application layer by creating abstraction for dbcontext.

Comment: Have a look at EF Core Power Tools.